# Using mongoexport to access all nested fields at once

Tags: python, mongodb

Currently I am able to access nested fields in MongoDB using the following example command:

mongoexport -h host -d abc -c xyz --csv --fields "degrees.1._id","degrees.0.departments.deptId" -- out output.csv

I am able to export the nested fields, but only one at a time by running the command repeatedly and changing the nested index every time (ie, degrees.x._id). Is there a method using mongoexport to obtain all the nested fields in a single command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do what you require if you want to output as CSV.

However, you can use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html) to reshape the document as required; e.g. using [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to unroll the array, [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) to reshape the documents, and dumping the results into a new collection using [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html).

Once you have the output collection, you can then use `mongoexport` on that collection.